# Find the value of $\sin (x)$ if $\cos(x)=\frac 1 3$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos (x)=\left (\frac{1}{3}\right)$$for $0°\lt\ x\lt90°$

Find the exact value of $\sin(x)$.
Give your answer as a surd.

I found the value with my calculator
$$\sin (x)=\left(\frac{\sqrt 8}{3}\right)$$

Is there a way of doing this by hand?

Comment: Hint: $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.

Comment: There are two possible values of $\sin x$ (in general, $\sin$ determines $\cos$ up to a sign and vice versa).

Comment: Form a triangle.

Comment: If the angle $x$ is acute, then $\sin x=\frac{\sqrt{8}}{3}$. Otherwise you can't tell more that the sine is either $\frac{\sqrt{8}}{3}$ or $-\frac{\sqrt{8}}{3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$

$\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$

$\sin x = \pm \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 x}$

$\sin x = \pm \sqrt{1 - \left( \frac 13\right)^2}$

$\sin x = \pm \sqrt{1 - \frac 19}$

$\sin x = \pm \sqrt{\frac 89}$

$\sin x = \pm \frac {\sqrt 8}3$

Answer (score 1):

We use

$$\sin^2 (x)=1-\cos^2 (x) $$

$$=1-\frac19=\frac89$$

thus $$\sin (x)=\pm \sqrt {\frac{8}{9}} $$

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1$$

it follows that:

$$\sin(x) = \pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)} = \pm\sqrt{1-1/9} = \pm\sqrt{8/9}= \pm \sqrt{8}/3$$

Answer (score 1):

From $\sin^2 x +\cos^2 x=1$ we have:

$\sin x=\pm \sqrt{1-\cos^2 x} =\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{9}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{8}{9}}=\pm \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin x = \pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2 x} = \pm\sqrt{1 - (\frac{1}{3})^2} = \pm\frac{\sqrt{8}}{3}$.

One would need to know the quadrant in which $x$ lies in to determine the "+" or "-" on the final answer.